# Is there a blockexplorer with a websocket API that includes relay IP address?

Tags: blockchain.info, blockexplorer

I have a visualization that shows realtime bitcoin transactions plotted on earth: https://blocks.wizb.it.

I relies on blockchain.info's websocket API, which used to include the relay IP per transaction but unfortunately it is now always including `0.0.0.0` instead of a public IP. I've [tweeted them about it](https://twitter.com/mikevanrossum/status/912630538741088258), but I am looking for an alternative. Does anyone know one?

I am running a full node already, however it is not well connected enough to do this myself and actually get more than 10 different peers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a blockchain.info API bug.

https://blockchain.info/rawtx/315d3cf722b73a2ad434dc3dba108bfb5ccdb13ea324bfa4d6e17ca3e741ad1f

`"relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",`

https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/315d3cf722b73a2ad434dc3dba108bfb5ccdb13ea324bfa4d6e17ca3e741ad1f?limit=50&includeHex=true

`"relayed_by": "213.239.196.9:8333",`

Note: I have no association with either API, but I have used Blockchain.info before, and know it can be buggy.

Also, relayed_by: 127.0.0.1 means that blockchain.info relayed it themselves.

Comment: Ah blockcypher also has a WS API, I can use this until blockchain.info recovers. Thanks!